# What can cause ASP scripting error with Mailgun SMTP?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, mailgun

I have an ASP3 script which should post to mailgun like below.
However when I click send, it thinks for like 20 seconds then throws an error:

CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'

The transport failed to connect to the server.

/ValidateOrder.asp, line 553

Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

thanks :)

````
Set myMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.mailgun.org"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 21
myMail.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "<username>"

'Your password on the SMTP server'

myMail.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "<password>"
myMail.Subject = "Subject" 

myMail.From = "<from email address>"
myMail.To = "<to email address>"
myMail.HTMLBody = mailtext
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update 
myMail.Send
set myMail = nothing ```
````

Comment: Port 21 seems strange SMTP port is usually 25.

Comment: Sinse you use SSL, try [port 587 or 465](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587/).

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to 465, now I get:

error '80040211'
/ValidateOrder.asp, line 553

Comment: With some SMTP servers, notably Office365, you should still use port 25, even with SSL, if you're using CDO to connect. What's your server setup? Some hosts will only let you use their own SMTP server or gateway. They can be very wary of people using their platform to distribute spam.

Comment: This is the MailGun SMTP server, so theoritically it should be working - I was actually directed to this site by their support. :)

Comment: My question was about your webserver, not your SMTP server.  I'm assuming that Mailgun is a dedicated email service and you're hosting your website with someone else.  Is the port you're using to access Mailgun open.  Some webhosts do not permit this and prefer you to use their own SMTP service.  And if you're trying to send from a local instance of IIS on your own PC, have you opened the relevant port on your own machine - it will probably be closed by default?

Comment: Sorry, it's a dedicated virtual server in Azure. The ASP script directly tries to communicate with Mailgun and all the relevant ports are opened.